# ubuntu 20.04 login loop after adding HDD

Tags: hard-drive, login

I have had ubuntu 20.04 running for ages and there have been few issues. Today I tried to add a new HDD to my system and it goes into a login loop.

I remove the SATA cable from the HDD and reboot, login works again as normal.

This didn't happen when I added a 2TB M.2 drive earlier this year, it is connected in SATA mode.

When connected to a USB to SATA bridge I can see the drive and all the files. The HDD does show up in the BIOS as the correct thing.

Comment: Check your $HOME mount is valid... if you cannot access the /home/$USER/ directory a login loop will occur, this could be because you've duplicate UUIDs for partitions, created errors in your *file-system table* or a number of other reasons (what you did in setup you didn't mention, but it reads like you made errors there but you didn't mention those steps so we can only guess about them))

Comment: Ok, so logging into the terminal, and going to /home/ shows no sub-directories. Running sudo mount -a gives the following error. EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem.

Comment: The next line says: /home wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing code pages or helper program, or other error.

Comment: As @guiverc says, the system cannot find my /home/adam directory so it goes into a login loop.